# Return Properties That Are The Same From Typed Collection

Tags: c#

I have a an object called **FooObject**:

```
public class FooObject
{
     public string Test1 {get; set;}
     public List<FooSubObject> SubTest1 {get; set;}
}
```

For later in the example, I also have a **DifferenceFooObject**:

```
public class DifferenceFooObject
{
     public string SharedTest1 { get; set; }
     public List<FooSubObject> SubTest1 {get; set;}
}
```

For later in the example, I also have a **FooSubObject**. **FooObject** has a property **SubTest1** that contains a typed collection of this type:

```
public class FooSubObject
{
     public string Test2 { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method that accepts a typed collection of **FooObject**. In this method, I need to calculate if any of the properties between the **FooObjects** within the typed collection parameter, have equal properties.

```
public DifferenceFooObject RunPropComparison(List<FooObject> foos)
{
     DifferenceFooObject difference = new DifferencFooObject();
     FooObject forComparison = foos.FirstOrDefault();
     IEnumerable<FooObject> intersectCollection = foos.Skip(1);

     // maybe do this using the first to compare the rest? No clue
}
```

I do not know the most efficient way to complete the above method. It is further complicated, at least IMHO, that the calculation has to take into account the properties of objects in collections that are a property of FooObject (looping through the properties of FooSubObject).

Here is the requested in/out:

```
List<FooObject> foos = new List<FooObject>();


FooObject obj = new FooObject();
obj.Test1= "Test1";
obj.SubTest1 = new List<FooSubObject>();

FooSubObject obj2 = new FooSubObject();
obj2.Test2 = "Test2";

obj.SubTest1.Add(obj2);

FooObject obj3 = new FooObject();
obj3.Test1= "Test1";
obj3.SubTest1 = new List<FooSubObject>();

FooSubObject obj4 = new FooSubObject();
obj4.Test2 = "Test3";

obj3.SubTest1.Add(obj2);
```

That's what would go in, ideally it would return that Test1 is the same across the board.

Comment: Some example input and output would be helpful.

Comment: any string really...and output type would the matching property value...

Comment: `List<FooObject> foos` is not a string. Show some examples of `List<FooObject>` inputs and the expected `DifferenceFooObject` output.

Comment: Edit your question, please. Code can be formatted nicer there.

Comment: I don't see how a `DifferenceFooObject` would express "Test1 is the same across the board." Please include example outputs, and include multiple examples. (since this appears to be talking about *differences*, I'd expect to see an example showing *differences*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best as I can tell, this is what you're looking for:

```
public IList<DifferenceFooObject> RunPropComparison(List<FooObject> foos)
{
    var differences = new List<DifferenceFooObject>();
    foreach (var group in foos.GroupBy(x => x.Test1))
    {
        var difference = new DifferenceFooObject();
        difference.SharedTest1 = group.Key;
        difference.SubTest1 = group.SelectMany(x => x.SubTest1).ToList();
        differences.Add(difference);
    }
    return differences;
}
```

Or if you add the following constructor:

```
public DifferenceFooObject(string sharedTest1, IEnumerable<FooSubObject> subTest1)
{
    this.SharedTest1 = sharedTest1;
    this.SubTest1 = subTest1.ToList();
}
```

Then you can make this code shorter:

```
public IList<DifferenceFooObject> RunPropComparison(List<FooObject> foos)
{
    return foos.GroupBy(x => x.Test1)
      .Select(g => new DifferenceFooObject(g.Key, g.SelectMany(x => x.SubTest1)))
      .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an especially efficient way of doing this. You will need to rely heavily on Reflection using the getProperties method to get at the values of the object properties...

You could look into using FasterFlect (http://fasterflect.codeplex.com/) which has better performance over standard .Net reflection...

Comment: reflection is fine with me

Comment: Why? OP seem to have one type to compare - I don't see need for relfection at all. Even if need to accept variety of types - passing lambda/delegate for comparison would take care of comparing without reflection... (Also it could be my misunderstanding of the question)

Comment: They talked about comparing all properties within the object and those properties could have nested properties. Which is why I said reflection...

Answer (score 0):

Check out this library. It compares two objects and tells you the different properties http://comparenetobjects.codeplex.com/documentation